# callback + параметры = замыкание...в голове

Tags: javascript, callback, замыкания

```
function first(y){
  y();
}

function second(r, b){
  console.log(r + b);
}

first(() => second(2, 3));
```

Как обойтись без вызова анонимной функции для передачи параметров **second()** в последней строчке моего решения (*пытался реализовать это в теле **first()** но у меня не вышло*), по условию нужно создать функцию которая принимает число как аргумент и возвращает другую функцию которая также принимает число как аргумент и возвращает сумму.

Comment: Так у тебя возврата функции в коде вообще нет.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function f(x) {
  return function (y) {
    return x + y
  }
}

console.log(f(1)(2))
```